# ASP.NET Regex Date Validation rejecting specific dates

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

This is a strange one, I'm currently working with a site that involves a bunch of input (as many do), I have a problem where my RegularExpressionValidator is flagging valid dates as incorrect, but only the following ones:

- 10th - 29th June
- All of February

Everything else works fine, and a postback is never sent to the server for it to do the validation so the code-behind can't be to blame. The only references in the code to the validation is as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValidFrom" runat="server" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" >
</asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValidFrom" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required"
    CssClass="errormessage" ControlToValidate="txtValidFrom">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidFrom" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtValidFrom" Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Date not in correct format" Text="Wrong format!"
    CssClass="errormessage"
    ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The regex string definitely works for all dates after 1900. Another strange thing is it's only this project that's having the issue, I've tested the above code on a fresh ASP.NET 2, 3 and 4 project, and it works fine, it validates the above dates as correct with no errors.

I can only imagine it's either something wrong with the deployment, or there's a conflict between the Javascript that ASP generates and something in the project (like jQuery); but i'd expect if that was the case, it wouldn't work at all - not just exclude pretty specific dates, and there's no JS errors being thrown at any time in the browser console.

Has anyone had any experiences with this kind of thing?  It seems to me a pretty strange problem due to the specific dates issue.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using a ui datepicker? p.s http://www.regexr.com/392nr - regex seems to be working fine.

Comment: Nope, the date is purely input by the user manually (I used a datepicker before but I think the webserver is .NET 2.0 which doesn't seem to be supported for those controls), but the only way it's input is with that textbox

Comment: One thing I can think with a free input such as that is that any spaces will invalidate the regex - see http://www.regexr.com/392o1

Comment: It's still invalidating when there's no spaces, i.e. I tried '22/01/2014' which worked, but '22/06/2014' didn't